# What happens during a AcquireTokenAsync call using the client certificate?

Tags: azure-active-directory

In Azure AD, when we make a call such as `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, new ClientAssertionCertificate(_clientId, _cert))` it is not clear what exactly happens.

What part of the certificate gets exchanged if any?

Is there a challenge/response taking place?

Is the private key needed on the client as a part of this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways you could go about finding the answer to you questions. One would be to look at the Microsoft Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for .NET [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet), since this is open-source. The other (which we'll do here) is to looking at the network request that `AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientAssertion)` generates, and work backwards from there.

Using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (or any other traffic analyzer), we can see something like the following (formatted for readability):

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net
&client_id={app-id}
&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N...VE8wHSf-HZvGQ
```

Breaking it down:

- `grant_type=client_credentials` tells us this is a token request using the [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) flow.
- `resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net` gives the URI of the resource the client is requesting an access token for. In this case, it's for the Azure AD Graph API.
- `client_id={app-id}` is the [client identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.2). In Azure AD, this is the app ID of the application that was registered.
- The presence of `client_assertion_type` and `client_assertion` are indicative that the client is using an  [assertion](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7521#section-1) to authenticate:
- `client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer` says that client assertion being used is a signed [JSON Web Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) (JWT).
- `client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N...VE8wHSf-HZvGQ` is the aforementioned signed JWT token. The authorization server (e.g. Azure AD) will validate the contents, and check that the token was indeed signed by the certificate authorized for the client in question.

So, what ADAL does is:

1. Construct a token with a set of claims about the client (your app)
2. Use your certificate's private key to generate a cryptographic signature of those claims
3. Bundle that up into a signed JWT
4. Make an appropriately formed token request to the authority

During `AcquireTokenAsync`, only the certificate's thumbprint is provided (it's included in the JWT header to help the authorization server look up the corresponding public key). The JWT's signature is what proves that the client is in possession of the private key. However, *before* `AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientAssertion)` can be used successfully, the client owner (i.e. you) needs to have provided Azure AD with the certificate's public key.

There is no challenge/response taking place here. The token is obtained in a single request, initiated by the client.

For a lot more detail, you can review the standards that this all implements:

- [RFC 6749: The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
- [RFC 7521: Assertion Framework for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7521)
- [RFC 7523: JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523)
- [RFC 7519: JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)

(Note that ADAL has a cache. Everything I described above will take place only if ADAL does not find a valid access token in the token cache. You can use `AuthenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear()` to clear the cache for experimentation.)